# Linux EC2 Broken Yum

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

I am having a *very very frustrating* problem with the `yum` command. Here's how I think it started:

I am running an EC2 server. A micro EC2 server. Today, I SSH'ed into the server and found '144 updates' awaiting me. Sure, I thought, go ahead.

After a little bit in the process, I started getting these errors:

```
error: Couldn't fork %post(openldap-2.4.23-32.21.amzn1.x86_64): Cannot allocate memory
```

Aha! I thought. Not enough ram, right? Stopped my instance, upgraded it to an m1.large instace (4GiB ram vs 613 MiB). Logged in, found about 100 updates ready. Ran `yum update`.

Now I get this:

Start off like this:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-main/primary_db                                                     | 2.4 MB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/primary_db                                                  | 7.8 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package authconfig.x86_64 0:6.1.12-10.16.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package authconfig.x86_64 0:6.1.12-13.17.amzn1 will be an update
```

Then does the `-->` thing for each update.

After it's done with that, it does this:

```
---> Package javapackages-tools.noarch 0:0.9.1-1.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt for package: javapackages-tools-0.9.1-1.2.amzn1.noarch
---> Package libgcc47.i686 0:4.7.2-8.72.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package numactl.x86_64 0:2.0.7-6.10.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package python-imaging.x86_64 0:1.1.6-19.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.7.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for libcom_err which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of libcom_err of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude libcom_err.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of libcom_err installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those arcitectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of libcom_err installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).
```

The does this:

```
      Protected multilib versions: libcom_err-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.i686 != libcom_err-1.42.3-2.16.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.24.amzn1.i686 != krb5-libs-1.9-33.22.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libblkid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 != libblkid-2.17.2-13.15.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.i686 != glibc-2.12-1.80.42.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgpg-error-1.10-3.10.amzn1.i686 != libgpg-error-1.10-1.9.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc47-4.7.2-8.72.amzn1.i686 != libgcc47-4.7.2-2.69.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libuuid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.i686 != libuuid-2.17.2-13.15.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libselinux-2.1.10-3.17.amzn1.i686 != libselinux-2.1.6-6.12.amzn1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: libsepol-2.1.7-3.12.amzn1.i686 != libsepol-2.1.3-2.11.amzn1.x86_64
```

Then this...

```
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 49 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
apr-util-1.4.1-4.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with apr-util-1.4.1-4.13.amzn1.x86_64
apr-util-ldap-1.4.1-4.14.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with apr-util-ldap-1.4.1-4.13.amzn1.x86_64
bash-4.1.2-14.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with bash-4.1.2-9.15.amzn1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.9.amzn1.x86_64
device-mapper-1.02.77-9.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with device-mapper-1.02.65-6.17.amzn1.x86_64
device-mapper-event-1.02.77-9.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with device-mapper-event-1.02.65-6.17.amzn1.x86_64
device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.77-9.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.65-6.17.amzn1.x86_64
device-mapper-libs-1.02.77-9.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with device-mapper-libs-1.02.65-6.17.amzn1.x86_64
file-5.11-4.12.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-5.07-6.11.amzn1.x86_64
file-libs-5.11-4.12.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with file-libs-5.07-6.11.amzn1.x86_64
generic-logos-17.0.0-2.5.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with generic-logos-16.0.0-1.4.amzn1.noarch
glibc-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.80.42.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.107.43.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-common-2.12-1.80.42.amzn1.x86_64
httpd-tools-2.2.24-1.29.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with httpd-tools-2.2.23-1.25.amzn1.x86_64
iproute-3.6.0-6.15.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with iproute-3.3.0-2.10.amzn1.x86_64
iptables-1.4.18-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with iptables-1.4.12-2.15.amzn1.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.24.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with krb5-libs-1.9-33.22.amzn1.x86_64
libblkid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libblkid-2.17.2-13.15.amzn1.x86_64
libcom_err-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libcom_err-1.42.3-2.16.amzn1.x86_64
libgcc47-4.7.2-8.72.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgcc47-4.7.2-2.69.amzn1.x86_64
libgpg-error-1.10-3.10.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libgpg-error-1.10-1.9.amzn1.x86_64
libselinux-2.1.10-3.17.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libselinux-2.1.6-6.12.amzn1.x86_64
libsepol-2.1.7-3.12.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libsepol-2.1.3-2.11.amzn1.x86_64
libss-1.42.3-3.17.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libss-1.42.3-2.16.amzn1.x86_64
libstdc++47-4.7.2-8.72.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libstdc++47-4.7.2-2.69.amzn1.x86_64
libuuid-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with libuuid-2.17.2-13.15.amzn1.x86_64
lvm2-libs-2.02.98-9.19.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with lvm2-libs-2.02.86-6.17.amzn1.x86_64
mysql55-common-5.5.30-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-common-5.5.29-1.27.amzn1.x86_64
mysql55-libs-5.5.30-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with mysql55-libs-5.5.29-1.27.amzn1.x86_64
nspr-4.9.2-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nspr-4.9.2-0.15.amzn1.x86_64
nss-3.14.0.0-12.28.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-3.13.6-2.27.amzn1.x86_64
nss-sysinit-3.14.0.0-12.28.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-sysinit-3.13.6-2.27.amzn1.x86_64
nss-tools-3.14.0.0-12.28.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-tools-3.13.6-2.27.amzn1.x86_64
nss-util-3.14.0.0-2.15.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with nss-util-3.13.6-1.14.amzn1.x86_64
openldap-2.4.23-32.21.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with openldap-2.4.23-26.17.amzn1.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.20-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with php-cli-5.3.20-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
php-common-5.3.20-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with php-common-5.3.20-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.20-1.31.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with php-pdo-5.3.20-1.30.amzn1.x86_64
python26-2.6.8-3.32.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with python26-2.6.8-3.30.amzn1.x86_64
python26-libs-2.6.8-3.32.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with python26-libs-2.6.8-3.30.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-4.8.0-32.40.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-4.8.0-27.39.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-libs-4.8.0-32.40.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-libs-4.8.0-27.39.amzn1.x86_64
rpm-python-4.8.0-32.40.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with rpm-python-4.8.0-27.39.amzn1.x86_64
setup-2.8.14-20.11.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with setup-2.8.14-16.10.amzn1.noarch
sudo-1.8.6p3-7.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with sudo-1.8.3p1-7.0.amzn1.x86_64
2:tar-1.26-12.13.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2:tar-1.23-7.10.amzn1.x86_64
tzdata-2013b-1.17.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with tzdata-2012f-1.15.amzn1.noarch
util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 is a duplicate with util-linux-ng-2.17.2-13.15.amzn1.x86_64
yum-3.2.29-40.25.amzn1.noarch is a duplicate with yum-3.2.29-30.24.amzn1.noarch
[root@ip-10-35-73-173 html]#
```

Any help would be appreciated *greatly!!!!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem I see in your output is that you interrupted a previous yum transaction before it could complete.

```
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
```

You really should do that before attempting to install or update anything else.

```
yum-complete-transaction
```

Once that's done, rule out any possible problems with your cache being out of sync with the repositories by clearing the local cache.

```
yum clean all
```

Finally, try again.

```
yum update
```

This might still fail, however, if Amazon's repos are actually out of sync. Unfortunately this happens far too often for my liking, which is one of the main reasons I don't recommend using Amazon Linux.

Comment: If it doesn't work, is it safe to just not use yum? Is there a way to point it to a different repo?

Comment: Didn't work. Do I just wait for the repo to get in sync again?

Comment: You'll probably have to wait for Amazon to fix it, or better yet, stop using Amazon Linux.

Comment: So my yum won't be broken forever?

Comment: It's Amazon. Who knows?

Comment: In my case, these were not enough and I had to make a `yum distro-sync`and it was fixed.

Comment: "yum clean all" solved the problems for me, thanks!